# How to pass json file data to Angular directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to pass a json file data that is created every time the show page is accessed. I am using one main parent object, "dashboard" to manipulate the data as a whole json tree. I have tried to refactor the Angular controller numerous times, using factories, but I am still getting the literal {{ resource }} output for each div.

this is the json array located in db/json/dashboard1.json :

```
   [{"id":1,"created_at":"2015-09-15T20:32:14.372Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T20:32:14.372Z","cruises":[{"id":1,"name":"Trogdor Cruises","ship_name":"Burninator","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.181Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.181Z","dashboard_id":1,"sailings":[{"id":70,"name":"Mexico Cruise","cruise_id":1,"main_image":"http://i.imgur.com/a82YKej.jpg","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.359Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.359Z","sailing_options":[{"id":13,"sailing_id":70,"price":350,"date":"Feb 18, 2016","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.540Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.540Z"},{"id":14,"sailing_id":70,"price":300,"date":"March 20, 2016","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.546Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.546Z"},{"id":15,"sailing_id":70,"price":250,"date":"June 30, 2016","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.591Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.591Z"}]}]}]
```

the file is very long but this is the gist of it. There are 4 levels of hierarchy. This is my main Angular file that contains the controller:

```
var dashboardCenter = angular.module('DashboardCenter', []);

    dashboardCenter.controller("dashboardController", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'db/jsondata/dashboard1.json'}).success(function(data){
        $scope.dashboard = data;
      });
}]);
```

This is the view that result that I am trying to achieve:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="DashboardCenter">
    <h1>Main Dashboard</h1>
    <div ng-controller="dashboardController">
        <div ng-repeat="cruise in dashboard.cruises">
            <div>{{ cruise.name }}</div>
            <div>{{ cruise.ship_name }}</div>
            <div ng-repeat="sailing in cruise.sailings"></div>
            <div>{{ sailing.name }}</div>
            <div>{{ sailing.main_image }}</div>
            <div ng-repeat="sailing_option in sailing.sailing_options">
                <div>{{ sailing_option.price}}</div>
                <div>{{ sailing_option.date}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also this is my rails controller that is creating the json file. Perhaps it is the culprit.

```
    class DashboardsController < ApplicationController

      respond_to :json

      def write_json(d)
        @dashb = Dashboard.where(id: 1)
        @dashboard = @dashb.to_json(:include => {:cruises =>
                        {:include => {:sailings =>
                        {:include => :sailing_options}}}})
        File.open("db/jsondata/dashboard1.json","w") do |f|
          f.write(@dashboard)
        end
      end

      def main_board
        @dashboard = Dashboard.where(id: 1)
        write_json(@dashboard)
      end
    end
```

I want to loop through each of the categories using ng-repeat with each being the parent of the next. I have looked for the answer for some time around the forum. I am sorry if this is a simple problem. I am very new to Angular. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing seems to work'? Do you see any result? Is there an error in your console? You should add an error handler to the $http call. Lastly, `data` in the success handler should already be an object, so there's no need to parse it.

Comment: This is the output that I am getting for each div: {{ cruise.name }}. Previously, I tried with a test controller and it was outputting the correct data, which would be the Cruise's name. I will change the Json.parce part in that case.

Comment: if your code is outputting the expressions `{{ }}`, then angular isn't loaded, for some reason or another.  what errors do you have in your console?

Comment: You have a few issues with this code.  First, your code is throwing errors because you are importing modules in the wrong place.  you should not be importing `$scope` or `$http` here: `var dashboardCenter = angular.module('DashboardCenter', ['$http', '$scope']);`.  Second, the hierarchy of your JSON file doesn't match the hierarchy of the HTML you are trying to output.

Comment: You are right, I changed the associations of my Dashboard model and now  the array is outputting correctly. I also took out the '$http' and $scope calls from the module and now the literal {{ }} expressions have disappeared. Presumably saying that angular is working? Still not displaying the right output though. I will update the code

Answer (score 0):

You had a few formatting errors in your code. But i got it working.
Change your array to:

```
[{"id":1, 
        "cruises":[{"id":1,"name":"Trogdor Cruises","ship_name":"Burninator", "dashboard_id":1}],
        "sailings":[{"id":70,"name":"Mexico Cruise","cruise_id":1,"main_image":"http://i.imgur.com/a82YKej.jpg","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.359Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.359Z"}],
        "sailing_options":[{"id":13,"sailing_id":70,"price":350,"date":"Feb 18, 2016","created_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.540Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T06:54:06.540Z"}]}];
```

Also change the display code in your html to

```
<body ng-controller="dashboardController">
<h1>Main Dashboard</h1>
<div ng-repeat="board in dashboard">
    <div ng-repeat="cruise in board.cruises">
        <div>{{ cruise.name }}</div>
        <div>{{ cruise.ship_name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="sailing in board.sailings">
        <div>{{ sailing.name }}</div>
        <div>{{ sailing.main_image }}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="sailing_option in board.sailing_options">
        <div>{{ sailing_option.price}}</div>
        <div>{{ sailing_option.date}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this, but it is still outputting the literal {{ resouce }} calls. Also each of these, is the parent of the next and they have to be outputted together. As it is they don't have an associative relationship with one another other that they all belong to dashboard. it should be dashboard>cruise>sailing>saling_options. Thank you for the prompt responce though.